# how can I write the function of two or more photocopies in a single <script>?

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to ask for help, how can I write the function of two or more mycopy in a single ?
I have a page where I have to insert more buttons that copy and I don't want to write the same  for each button.
Thank you all

```
enter code here
 <button onClick="mycopy('copia')">copy</button></p>
 <div id="copia" >
 <p>[text1]</p>
 </div>
 <p><script>
 function mycopy (containerid) {
  var textarea = document.createElement('textarea')
  textarea.id = 'temp_element'
  textarea.style.height = 0
  document.body.appendChild(textarea)
  textarea.value = document.getElementById(containerid).innerText
  var selector = document.querySelector('#temp_element')
  selector.select()
  document.execCommand('copy')
   document.body.removeChild(textarea)
  }
 </script></p>
<button onClick="mycopy1('copia1')">copy</button></p>
<div id="copia1">
<p>[text2 ]</p>
</div>
<p><script>
function mycopy1 (containerid) {
var textarea = document.createElement('textarea')
textarea.id = 'temp_element'
textarea.style.height = 0
document.body.appendChild(textarea)
textarea.value = document.getElementById(containerid).innerText
var selector = document.querySelector('#temp_element')
 selector.select()
  document.execCommand('copy')
  document.body.removeChild(textarea)
   }
  </script></p>
```

Comment: Sorry, unless I'm missing something obvious, why can't you just call `mycopy('copia1')`??

Comment: you're absolutely right, I'm sorry but sometimes the solution is so trivial that I went to complicate my life!
Thank you very much for helping